# How can I extend jade layout from a view/parent/child structure?

Tags: node.js, layout, express, pug

I have my Views structured like this

[image]

I wanted to extend the layout.jade to all jades under my user folder. 
Doing extends ../layout in the files under user folder doesn't work.  There are no much writing about extending layouts that discuss about this.

Does Express allows this kind of extends?

Answer (score 6):

`extends ../layout` should work fine. Here is how I structure my views. What happens when you try to render the child template? Are you using blocks like I am, or includes?

```
// ls
+views
  +children
    -child.jade
  -layout.jade
  -sister.jade
-app.js

// layout.jade
!!!
html
  head
    script
      console.log('hi ho');
    block head
  body
    #wrapper
      block content

// sister.jade
extends layout
block append head
  style
    h1{ text-align: center}
block append content
  h1 Hello World

// children/child.jade
extends ../layout
block append content
  h1 Hello World
```