# Login form in header Node.js Jade template

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a Jade file called `header.jade`, with a mini login form which is included to all views, what is route concept for getting this post?

```
header
    nav(class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation")
        .navbar-header
            button(type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse")
                span(class="sr-only") Toggle navigation
                span(class="icon-bar")
                span(class="icon-bar")
                span(class="icon-bar")
                a(class="navbar-brand") mailMessenger
        form(action="/login", method="post" class="form-inline minilogin" role="form")
                .form-group
                    label(class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2") Username
                    input(type="text", name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="username")
                .form-group
                    label(class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2") password
                    input(type="text", name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="password")
                .checkbox
                    label
                        input(type="checkbox")
                        | Remember me
                    button(type="submit" class="btn btn-default") Sign in
```

Comment: You can use extend and blocks like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058055/how-can-i-extend-jade-layout-from-a-view-parent-child-structure

Comment: What do you mean by "route concept for getting this post"? Do you mean you want the POST data?