# Bootstrap rendering a blank white page - node js- express - jade

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I am trying to get the bootstrap working for Node.js with Jade template engine.

It just renders a blank white page when I try to run the index.jade file.

```
div.topbar
  div.fill
    div.container
      a.brand(href='#') #{title}
      ul.nav

      form.pull-right(method="post", id="loginForm")
        input.input-small(id="username", type="text", name="User", placeholder="Username")
        input.input-small(id="password", type="password", name="Password", placeholder="Password")
        input.btn.primary(type="submit", value="Sign In")
      p#loginPrompt.pull-right.login-prompt
```

when i run this I get something like this.

[image]

but when I try to include extends layout (see image below)where I have the bootstrap styles defined.
I get a blank page.
[image]

Can anyone please explain me how to set this bootstrap working.
I have the bottstrap css file in stylesheets folder under public and the js file under javascripts in public folder.

layout.jade

```
doctype
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
  body
    block content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include `block content` like so:

```
extends ./layout.jade
block content
    div.topbar
      div.fill
        div.container
          a.brand(href='#') #{title}
          ul.nav

          form.pull-right(method="post", id="loginForm")
            input.input-small(id="username", type="text", name="User", placeholder="Username")
            input.input-small(id="password", type="password", name="Password", placeholder="Password")
            input.btn.primary(type="submit", value="Sign In")
          p#loginPrompt.pull-right.login-prompt
```

I tested that this works with the layout.jade that you showed.

Comment: i have just extends layout in another file aboutus.jade which just has text.
That file shows up just right on the UI

it is this index.jade that shows a blank page

Comment: Oh ok-- how about `block content` ? That is in layout.jade, but it doesn't look like you declare it in index.jade

Comment: nope i have tried with the extends layout and block content. it did not work either

Comment: Cool! All I did was write two lines, so it's either the first one and your path was not correct, or it's the second one and you forgot to define the block. If you don't define that block, then layout.jade won't be provided any content to insert. And of course, indentation is important in Jade.

Comment: Allright Roman, Thank you again! :)
I should be more careful with indents

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake when you are trying to reference your jade layout. Use **extends./layout.jade** if that does not work here is a link for a similar problem [Extending Jade Differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058055/how-can-i-extend-jade-layout-from-a-view-parent-child-structure)